# preg_match html code <request></request>

Tags: php, curl, preg-match

I use cURL to send request to server this is link: [Server Side script for cURL request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21082271/server-side-script-for-curl-request/21082365)
and i read sended data with file_get_contents('php://input');
but i have some nasty data arround my xml. So i think to use preg_match to select xml only.
Something like this:

```
$arq = file_get_contents('php://input');
$wanted="/\<request\>(.*?)\<\/request\>/i";
preg_match($wanted, $arq, $result);
echo $result;
```

This is content of $arq:

```
------------------------------9e2a86ef9445
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="data"

<request>
<session>
 <user>exampleuser</user>
 <pass>examplepass</pass>
</session>
</request>
------------------------------9e2a86ef9445--
```

how can I read everything between 
becouse content inside it is not static, it is dinamic and could be different on separated requests.

Thank you a lot.

Comment: ...and what isn't working?

Comment: @NielsKeurentjes I don't have any output, I am now familiar with preg_match very well. I don't know all parameters and could not find them on net.

Comment: [Did you try reading the flimsy manual?](http://nl3.php.net/preg_match)

Comment: DOMDocument, as natewiley says.

Comment: The content between the request tags could span lines, so you might need to try adding the /s flag (.../si). I don't think you need to escape the < and > characters, but it shouldn't _hurt_ to do so. If nothing else works, try changing \< and \> to just < >. Finally, can there be a request tag _inside_ another request tag? If so, a single regexp probably won't do the job.

Comment: @PhilPerry <request> tag is unique. that is why I had put it there. I am trying this right now.

Comment: i think you might need to add PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE http://us3.php.net/preg_match

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of this regex originally written by [`Gumbo`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/53114/gumbo) modified by me to suit your needs.

```
<?php
$html='------------------------------9e2a86ef9445
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="data"

<request>
<session>
 <user>exampleuser</user>
 <pass>examplepass</pass>
</session>
</request>
------------------------------9e2a86ef9445--';
$tagname = 'request';

$pattern = '/<'.preg_quote($tagname, '/').'(?:[^"\'>]*|"[^"]*"|\'[^\']*\')*>(.*?)<\/'.preg_quote($tagname, '/').'>/s';
preg_match_all($pattern, $html, $matches);

echo $thefilteredXML = $matches[0][0];
```

**OUTPUT (as if in browser's view source) :**

```
<request>
<session>
 <user>exampleuser</user>
 <pass>examplepass</pass>
</session>
</request>
```

Comment: Thank you a lot for your effort. when I run it as you write it, it is working fine but on the place of nasty data I have: ------------------------------c2fcc86c240b
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="data"
 and when i run it like that it is not working again. what could problem be?

Comment: @mandza, Please see the edited answer. I have the same content as you have posted on your question. It returns the same output. Press ctrl+U to view the source to see the tags.

Answer (score 1):

You should check out php's [DOMDocument](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php), and [DOMXpath](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php).. You'll hug yourself :)  It is extremely powerful. No regex needed. I personally do quite a bit of web scraping myself.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but is there any example related to my question. Becouse it will take time to figure out use of DomDocument the way I want to use.

Comment: Are you only dealing with XML?

Comment: yes just XML. I send data with cURL over POST with XML becouse sended data is very large, about 100KB

Comment: You could use simple_xml_load_file() http://php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-file.php

Comment: I had try simplexml becouse I am familiar with it but it didnt work. I am updating my question with exact output.

Answer (score 1):

Ain't this simple using [`DOMDocument`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) Class ?

```
<?php
$html='some nasty data
<request>
<session>
 <user>exampleuser</user>
 <pass>examplepass</pass>
</session>
</request>
and samo nasty data here';

$dom = new DOMDocument;
@$dom->loadHTML($html);
foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('session') as $tag) {
    echo $tag->nodeValue."<br>";
}
```

**OUTPUT :**

```
exampleuser
examplepass
```

Comment: seems like he actually wants to preserve the xml structure and not just get the values by removing the junk data. IMO.

Comment: @Pjack you have right. Becouse xml structure is different on separated requests

Comment: @mandza, So you just need this `<request><session><user>exampleuser</user><pass>examplepass</pass></session></request>` ??

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran yes!

Comment: @mandza, Please see my other answer. Let this answer be here as it may help others.